# Remove "pc" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I see a lot of questions tagged [pc](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pc) that are really better tagged with [windows](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) or [linux](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) as a lot of them are operating-system specific.

Example:

["MTP USB Device" driver error (screenshot) when connecting my Galaxy S to my PC in Kies mode -- How can I resolve this problem?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3246/mtp-usb-device-driver-error-screenshot-when-connecting-my-galaxy-s-to-my-pc-i)

This is really a Windows question.

I've only seen a few that are "generic" enough to warrant the PC tag, this being one of them:

[Shutting down Android phone from PC](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5099/how-to-shutdown-android-phone-from-pc)

Comment: See also: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/439/desktop-os-tags

Answer (score 5):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to agree. Go ahead and start hitting that "edit" link.

I have updated the tag-wiki for [pc](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pc) to direct people to more specific tags. It might help.